# How can I limit the numer of characters displayed by this code?

Tags: json, character, limit

I'm using this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
 $.getJSON("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/USERNAME.json?callback=?", function(data) {
  $(".show_tweet").html(data[0].text);
 });
});
</script>

<div class='show_tweet'></div>
```

to display the latest tweet on my website, however I wish to limit the number of characters this displays to let's say 75 chars. How do I do this?

Thanks for the replies, Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this

```
 function(data) {

   if(data[0].text.length > 75)
         $(".show_tweet").html(data[0].text.substring(0,75));
   else
         $(".show_tweet").html(data[0].text);
 });
});
```

Comment: Is it also possible to have 3 dots "..." in the end added automatically? And if yes, is it possible to link those dots (to twitter)